# Can two threads read from the same QList at the same time?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qlist

Pretty new to threading and I have this QList that the threads share between them. They all have their own space that they can work on, and the GUI (the model/view) access this list constantly. I then get this crash which points to QDataList.size(). The debugging doesn't really help me since I never come across this issue if I step through the code and when I'm trying to what qList that's crashing, there's no info available.

So, my question is: Is it possible to get the Qlists size and read objects at the same time? The objects in the list are thread safe and cant be read/write by different threads at the same time.

Getting "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefefa." which points me to:
inline int size() const in qlist.h

I walk through the call stack and found this:

```
QtCored4.dll!QListData::size()  Line 98 + 0x11 bytes    C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QList<enum QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::InternalNotifications>::size()  Line 137 + 0x10 bytes  C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::resumeNotificationHandling()  Line 444 + 0xe bytes    C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::finished()  Line 797  C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QNetworkAccessBackend::finished()  Line 313 C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QNetworkAccessHttpBackend::replyFinished()  Line 739    C++
QtNetworkd4.dll!QNetworkAccessHttpBackend::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a)  Line 86 + 0x8 bytes    C++
QtCored4.dll!QMetaCallEvent::placeMetaCall(QObject * object)  Line 525 + 0x1d bytes C++
QtCored4.dll!QObject::event(QEvent * e)  Line 1195 + 0x14 bytes C++
QtGuid4.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e)  Line 4550 + 0x11 bytes  C++
QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e)  Line 3932 + 0x10 bytes    C++
QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)  Line 876 + 0x15 bytes    C++
QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)  Line 231 + 0x39 bytes C++
QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver, int event_type, QThreadData * data)  Line 1500 + 0xd bytes   C++
QtCored4.dll!qt_internal_proc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned int wp, long lp)  Line 496 + 0x10 bytes C++
```

Every thread is having a network manager that does a networkRequest:

[QThread ASSERT failure in QMutexLocker: "QMutex pointer is misaligned",](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458664/qthread-assert-failure-in-qmutexlocker-qmutex-pointer-is-misaligned#comment11968392_9458664)

Comment: Any QList member function that is not `const` can potentially modify its state.

Comment: Have you tried synchronizing using a lock? http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qreadwritelock.html

Comment: the different threads will be changing objects in the list, not adding or deleiting objects from it

Comment: using operator[] to find the objects and change them. maybe thats where im doing wrong

Comment: Is anything else modifying the list with new data?

Comment: nope. nothing is adding/deleting to it during processing

Comment: It's conceivable that `QList` caches the node associated with the last `operator[]` access, in order to use it as a hint to accelerate subsequent accesses. Try using a constant reference to the `QList`, to ensure that you're only using `const` (immutable) methods.

Comment: Qt containers are thread-safe if they are used as read-only containers by **all** threads used to access them. So either one or more of your threads are modifying the list or your problem is something else in the code.

Comment: I looked at the call stack and the issue seem to be somewhere else.

Comment: @ArnoldSpence, there is no guarantee of thread-safety for Qt containers. They are reentrant only (according to the Qt docs).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, I was quoting the documentation and the condition is "read-only accesss". http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html

Comment: @Arnold, indeed, the generic containers documentation does state that, though the QList documentation, and thread-safe/reentrant docs do not. I'd hope they are actually read-only safe...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize that its possible to pre-allocate a QList and let threads operate on different areas of that list, but in my opinion I think its a bad pattern to follow.

When I work with Qt (I actually work with PyQt since I'm a python programmer), I feel its best to make use of the signal/slot mechanism that is provided to you and never share memory between threads. Each thread should be given its own data either directly at creation, or over time through a queue that is waits on. When it is done with its work or a chunk of work it can emit a signal with the data. You would have a single handler that connects to all of your threads to listen for data to be ready.

The result of this pattern is that you aren't sharing memory and you don't have to worry so much about locks, but rather just waiting for workers to signal their data is ready, and a single handler is collecting and updating the main model.

That being said, here is another reference of someone using a QList as shared memory and experiencing crashes until they locked it: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/13049

I think when people (myself included) first start working with thread the immediate impulse is to just use containers the same way they always have. But once you start threading you immediately already increase both the complication of the codes logic as well as the capacity for bugs. Synchronization of shared memory is one way to approach it, using mutexes to lock resources before access. But I think its worth mentioning another way which is communicating.

Googles Go language was built with one of its core principles being: "Dont communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating" http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/

Go wanted to address this issue at its core by communicating memory over channel objects, which resemble signal/slot in Qt. One component has exclusive local access to memory and then pass it along to another component over a channel. This gurantees you wont have race conditions. Anyways just thought I would tack on this extra reference because I feel its very relevant to thread programming issues.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure if I can easily split up the data since the set will be pretty big and the indexes of every object corelates to the index in the model(model/view). So if one objects is changed, a signal will be sent to the model which notifies the view what object (row) that just changed. No point changing the entire list. I could, I guess, changed the main list by calling the model.setData

Comment: I wonder why I got two downvotes on this one. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: @chikuba Just emit a list of vector of data. Send it in chunks.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>No, they can't</strike> Err, maybe/probably. The documentation says that all QList functions are only `reentrant`, and not thread-safe. Now, normally reading from a shared structure should be thread-safe, but in this case Qt has explicit documentation and there is no exception made for reading. You therefore have to assume that it is not allowed and may result in errors.

Note that a `std::list` does not suffer from this problem and allows reading from multiple threads (writing must of course still be exclusive).

Note that Qt threading overall has a lot of special cases, it is was prompted me to write "[requirements for a threaded API](http://mortoray.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/requirements-for-a-concurrent-threaded-library-api/)", many of which Qt fails. Part of this is history, and part of this is dealing with a variety of hardware, but in general Qt threading must be treated specially.

---

Since the docs are not consistent (see comment) I did a quick review of the QList source code. Simple functions like "begin", "size" and "first" do appear to be read-only. They do not modify the data structure. Thus if they are causing a crash it is because some other thread is modifying the list at the same time.

Comment: Arnold points out that the generic containeer docs do indeed make the read-only guarantee. One would assume this then applies to Qlist, but the docs are thus not consistent.

Comment: I found the issue. It had to do with Networkreply and Qt checking its size even though it should been used up and ready to delete by then, but I guess not