# Qt Model-View data and model in separate thread

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

Previously, I asked about running model and view in different threads and now, I understand how it poses a problem. To circumvent the problem, I was thinking of duplication of data. When data is modified by the worker thread, it simultaneously sends an update to GUI/Model thread to update the model with the same data (so there exist a exact copy of data with the GUI/model).

Does this sound like a plausible approach? Other method is to use direct widgets with default models like QTableWidget etc. but then I need to do a lot of things that are powered by QTableView by default.

Please suggest!

**Link to other question:** [Design Pattern, Qt Model/View and multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485339/design-pattern-qt-model-view-and-multiple-threads)

Comment: Sounds good. You can use queued signal/slot connections for the updates. Unless you have huge amount of updates or the data is very expensive to copy, I don't see a problem. If the worker doesn't need to keep the existing data, it can just send updates and forget, to avoid duplicated RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios that are possible but in either case you will need at least 2 objects as follows:

**Data Object**

Contains all functions required for maintaining and manipulating data.  Data is stored in Pointers to objects describing data.  Data Structures for this I will leave up to you.

**Model**

Contains a vector of pointers to data that is currently being displayed

*Scenario 1*

Data in `QTableView` is display only in which case on a `QTimer` signal or a different signal the data storage is locked and vector for **display model** is cut and put into the model and `reset()` is called to have `QTableView` repainted with new data.

*Scenario 2*

You can manipulate data via custom `ItemEditor` in `QTableView`.  In this case the top widget that has `QTableView` should have references to your **data object** and `QTableView` and a signal handler for the signal emitted by the `ItemEditor` when the edit is complete.  This signal handler will then lock the data structure inside **data object** and update it, once done it may cut a new vector to display but more often then not it won't have to.

How you will set up the locking, searching, etc is entirely up to you.