# Qt Passing "this" as a parent when building a QObject that is moved to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

After reading the documentation I came across this:

> The child of a `QObject` must always be created in the thread where the parent was created. This implies, among other things, that you should never pass the `QThread` object (this) as the parent of an object created in the thread (since the `QThread` object itself was created in another thread).

I'm not really sure what this means so I made a few examples and was wondering where this would apply.

A.

```
class MyThread : public QThread {
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {
        QNetworkAccessManager *test = new QNetworkAccessManager (this); 
       // here I assume that this child(test) will have the main thread (creator of MyThread)
       // as it's parent and it will go horrible wrong. 
    }
    ....
}
```

B.

```
class MyThread : public QThread {
    QNetworkAccessManager *test;
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {}

    void run {
       test = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); 
       // will the main thread be the parent here aswell?
       // if I remove "this" this will work since its created in the thread (not the main thread)
    }
    ....
}
```

Okey, but how about this?

Notice that these object will be created and started like this:

```
MyThread *fakeThread = new MyThread; // should I or should I not pass "this" as a parent here?
QThread realThread;

fakeThread->moveToThread(&realThread);

realThread.start();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(fakeThread, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

C.

```
class MyThread : public QObject {
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
        QNetworkAccessManager *test = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); 
       // I assume this constructor still will be create the the QNAM as a child to 
       // the main thread and it will not work
    }

    void start {
        ....
    }
}
```

D.

```
class MyThread : public QObject {
    QNetworkAccessManager *test;
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    void start {
       test = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); 
       // What about now? 
    }
    ....
}
```

I really want to implement the option D so that I have a hirerchy of objects that can easily be deleted. For example if I wanna read a big number of files, and I want all of them to be de-allocated when the thread dies.

Also, what is the main difference between the `QThread` derived version and the one where you move the `QObject` to a thread? The documentation always states the do and don't when working with `Qthread`, but I'm a bit unsure about this.

My biggest issue now is that I have a class that is derived from `QObject` that will be moved to a thread. In that object I create a another object. That object contains a `QNetworkAccessManager` and a `QFile`. Where would I pass "this" as a parent, or should I not do that at all when being in a thread? Please explain.

At the moment, the object(let's call it `RestHandler`) that belongs to object(`uploader`, which is a thread) is created on the heap. This is because most of the function uses it and if it's created in the header file on the stack, its parent will be the main thread. The in the `RestHandler` a `QNetworkAccessManager` will be created on the stack.

Edit:

After reading the answers I tried to create both the `restHandler` and the `QNetworkAccessManager` on the stack and then move them. The output was the following:

> `Resthandeler` constructor: `restHandler` created in thread 
>   `QThread`(0x22d5e8) with a accessManager in thread  `QThread`(0x22d5e8) 
>   current location QThread(0x22d5e8)

Then when I try to move the `resthandler` I get the following warning:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1fbf0e0) is not the object's thread (0x22d5e8).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1fbf0e0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x42a477c), parent's thread is QThread(0x22d5e8), current thread is QThread(0x4196f98)
```

I guess there is no way of solving this? The program seems to run and the slots are being called in the right threads, but it seems to be a question of time before it crashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458664/qthread-assert-failure-in-qmutexlocker-qmutex-pointer-is-misaligned/9458753#9458753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Threads and QObjects documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html):

> Event driven objects may only be used in a single thread.
>   Specifically, this applies to the timer mechanism and the **network
>   module.** For example, you cannot start a timer or connect a socket in a
>   thread that is not the object's thread.

For you, this means your `QNetworkAccessManager` needs to be in the thread where you will be connecting sockets etc.  It can't be a child of your `MyThread` object, and if it initialized in your constructor, it needs to be moved the `MyThread` after the thread has been started.

> You must ensure that all objects created in a thread are deleted
>   before you delete the QThread. This can be done easily by creating the
>   objects on the stack in your run() implementation.

Is there a reason you're allocating the `QNetworkAccessManager` on the heap?  Can you have it be a plain member (on the stack) instead?

From the [QNetworkAccessManager docs:](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)

> The Network Access API is constructed around **one QNetworkAccessManager
>   object**, which holds the common configuration and settings for the
>   requests it sends. It contains the proxy and cache configuration, as
>   well as the signals related to such issues, and reply signals that can
>   be used to monitor the progress of a network operation. **One
>   QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt application.**

This suggests to me that you may want to rethink the design decision behind having multiple threads with this type of object, and whether you can follow the intended usage pattern instead.  You can still have many worker threads that connect via [threadsafe signal/slot connections](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) to a single instance of the `QNetworkAccessManager` which belongs in the main thread.

Comment: The AccessManager can only do 6 request at the same time, I need 8. Also, I cannot figure out how to know which request would belong to what item in a list (of files that needs to be uploaded where every file has a progressbar)

Comment: get QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x4259ddc), parent's thread is QThread(0x2cd5e8), current thread is QThread(0x42c62b0) When I try to allocate on the stack. 0x2cd5e8 is the main thread

Comment: Is it cus its a private variable I declare in the header and it will then be created on the main threads stack?

Comment: If you create it on the stack, it will be a child of the main thread, that's correct.  You should move it to the new thread, after starting said new thread.  Once it is moved, you can create new children of the QNetworkAccessManager.  `QObject::moveToThread`

Comment: @chikuba Your first comment, about not knowing which request belongs to which item in a list, makes me think there's something off about the object-oriented-ness of your setup.  You should think about encapsulating all relevant elements of a given functionality, such as keeping track of progress etc., or linking the requests with the items in the list, into an object.

Comment: So if I get this right; all the objects that are created or moved to "this" in the "run()" function, their children will belong to the current thread, not the main one? And if my program is working with multiple instances of the qnetworkaccessmanager, what are the reasons for me to rebuild the entire thing? I need to be able to run 8 threads at the same time which all makes requests, on at the time. And the check when they are done to run another request from on of the files in the shared list.

Comment: First, it sounds like you've got it.  I suggest trying it and seeing what happens.  Second, **if** it is working with multiple QNetworkAccessManagers, great - I would worry a bit about if that is guaranteed behavior though, since the documentation specifically mentions a single instance being the preferred route.  There may be something hidden in the implementation that you don't see everywhere, a limit to the network connections or something - I don't know.  All I can say is, try it out!

Comment: If you have a look at the NetworkReply/request doc it only emits signals it only emits signals with two variables: recived and total. The accessManagar doesnt emit ANY signal that has anything to do with how much data u've been uploading, only when the entire thing is done "finish(reply)". This would mean that I would heaps of replys. I actually have no idea how to solve it. Now I have one reply per thread that points to the most recent call.

Comment: Also, having just one networkmanagar and access it from different threads, wouldnt that be a lot of locking and stuff going on? and queued connection. Even thought you just said that it would not be accessed from different threads at the same time? And that solution wouldn't be scalable. But yes, I see where you are comming from and I gave it a lot of thought

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/network-download.html In that example you seem to choose between parallel and progressbar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8329/discussion-between-tmpearce-and-chikuba)

Comment: Note: It is not "the limit of the network connection". It is a limit of 6 connections parallel (!) on desktop app.

Meaning creating a new QNetworkManager means every manager can run 6 connections parallel.

Comment: Example: If you create 10 QThread for example and every thread has a QNetworkManager, you can run 60 (!) requests parallel within one application, which is insane and probably not wanted.